# How to import a local file.json with Vue.js and D3.js

Tags: json, vue.js, d3.js

I'm trying to work with a local file.json with vue.js and D3.js

d3 doesn't find the file on the devServer, i can import it in a const in Vue.js but d3 can't read it, because d3.json is a http request (i guess).

I tried this

```
d3.json("../assets/map.json")
```

and

```
import map from './assets/map.json'
```

and

```
const map = "./assets/map.json"
```

I created a SimpleHTTPServer with python but i get a CORS policy error, i tried to change vue.config.js

```
    proxy: "http://localhost",
  },
```

and then call

```
d3.json(http://localhost:8080/map.json)
```

but nothing worked...

Thanks for your help

Riton

Comment: This is not related to Vue in my opinion, if you have a server running correctly the `d3.json` (which uses Fetch internally) should get the file. What is the error message? Also, is the html with the script in the same folder of assets? In that case it would be `"./assets/map.json"`, with just one dot.

Comment: Unfortunately i tried all the possibles paths ... And my project works, but when i want to incorporate it in a vue.js project, it can't find the file (error 404)..

Answer (score 0):

I put my file.json in "public" directory, it was in "assets", and everything is ok.